# Flask-sqlalchemy equivalent to multiple WHERE conditions querying a database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have successfully queried a database with MySQL.connector:

```
search_term = form.searchstring.data
mycursor.execute('''SELECT *
                    FROM post
                    WHERE title like '%'''+search_term+'''%'
                    OR description like '%'''+search_term+'''%'
                    OR priority like '%'''+search_term+'''%'
                    OR date_posted like '%'''+search_term+'''%'
                    OR time_posted like '%'''+search_term+'''%'
                    OR date_closed like '%'''+search_term+'''%'
                    OR time_closed like '%'''+search_term+'''%'
                    OR status like '%'''+search_term+'''%'
                    OR assigned_to like '%'''+search_term+'''%'
                    OR reported_by like '%'''+search_term+'''%'
                    ;''')
res =  mycursor.fetchall()
```

I am struggling with the flask-sqlalchemy equivalent for the above. I.e...

```
res = Post.query.########
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
search_term = "%{}%".format(search_string)
res=Post.query.filter(Post.title.like(search_term) | Post.description.like(search_term) 
 ..go on with all the filters... | Post.reported_to.like(search_term)).all()
```